# Guardar index para reutilizar

Tags: angular5

Hola buenas mi problema es que necesito imprimir una sublista que va en un `tr` aparte debajo del `tr` donde hago el bucle (en el ng-container), pero una vez fuera de ese `tr` (donde hago el bucle) la `i` ya no me la reconoce. ¿Alguna idea?. Muchas gracias

```
<table class="procedures-table__grid">
    <caption class="sr-only"><h3>Select next procedure</h3></caption>
    <thead class="procedures-table__grid__header">
      <tr>
        <th id="procedure_procedure" class="">Trámite</th>
        <th id="procedure_regulatory-reform" class="">Reforma normativa</th>
        <th id="procedure_options" class=""></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr [indicator] = i *ngFor="let procedure of tableListProcedures, index as i">
        <td headers="procedure-procedure">
          <button (click)="openCloseTab(i);" class="">
            {{procedure.procedureName}}
          </button>
          <!-- <i class="adriano-arrow-down" attr.aria-hidden=""></i> -->
        </td>
        <td headers="procedure_regulatory-reform">
          <a (click)="goReformProcedure();" href="#" class="">
            {{procedure.regulatory_reform_Procedure}}
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <ng-container *ngIf="i">

      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table
```

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo: para cada *procedure* quieres añadir un TR con un botón con su nombre, ¿seguido de otros TR con información de ese procedure?

Comment: Cada procedure cuando sea pulsado desplegara nº subprocedures. Es como un acordeón pero claro debe saber a que posición del array pertenece. Yo lo he pensado para que se despliegen como unas filas mas de la tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agrupar dentro de una etiqueta ng-template:

```
  <tbody>
    <ng-template *ngFor="let procedure of tableListProcedures, index as i">
      <tr [indicator] = "i" >
        <td headers="procedure-procedure">
          <button (click)="openCloseTab(i);" class="">
            {{procedure.procedureName}}
          </button>
          <!-- <i class="adriano-arrow-down" attr.aria-hidden=""></i> -->
        </td>
        <td headers="procedure_regulatory-reform">
          <a (click)="goReformProcedure();" href="#" class="">
            {{procedure.regulatory_reform_Procedure}}
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <ng-container *ngIf="i">
        ... 
        ¿¿¿ <tr *ngFor="let subprocedure of procedure.subprocedures"> ???
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias me sirvió.

Comment: Te agradecería que marcases entonces la respuesta como aceptada, para que la pregunta aparezca como respondida :)